# -browserTimeout does not seem to change timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am running a selenium server on my local machine and passing in a suite of selenese tests (the browser is being run on a virtual display with Xvfb)

```
DISPLAY=:99 \
java -jar ../automated-test-builder/selenium-server*.jar \
-port 4444 \
-timeout 7200 \
-browserTimeout 180 \
-htmlSuite "*firefox /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox"
http://testsite.com \
suite.html \
../compiledTests/suites/results.html
```

However no matter what I have tried with the -browserTimeout option I am still getting occasional timeout issues after 30000 ms (30seconds)? How can I increase the timeout for each action?

Comment: [Se2 experts suggest NOT USE IMPLICIT WAIT](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12412/7552) at all. Especially don't mix them with explicit waits.

Comment: did you tried explicit waits?

Answer (score 2):

[Se2 experts suggest NOT USE IMPLICIT WAIT](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12412/7552) at all. Especially don't mix them with explicit waits.

Jim Evans is Se2 core team member so he should know.

Comment: the question was unrelated to selenium's implicit waits.

Answer (score 1):

`-browserTimeout` specifies the timeout before the browser closes after Selenium becomes idle. For example when your test ends, but you do not call `driver.quit()`

Both timeout and browsertimeout are documented at: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-timeouts-version-221-required

> On the hub, setting the -timeout command line option to "30" seconds
>   will ensure all resources are reclaimed 30 seconds after a client
>   crashes. On the hub you can also set -browserTimeout 60 to make the
>   maximum time a node is willing to hang inside the browser 60 seconds.
>   This will ensure all resources are reclaimed slightly after 60
>   seconds. All the nodes use these two values from the hub if they are
>   set. Locally set parameters on a single node has precedence, it is
>   generally recommended not to set these timeouts on the node.

For shorting or enlarging wait times for elements have a look at Explicit Waits: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp You can set the wait timeout there per element you are searching for.

The [WebDriver timeouts](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) also do not let you override the default timeouts, do not confuse implicit wait for this. It is advised not to use implicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

What about to set on the start of your selenese test set the setSpeed/setTimeout commands?

```
Command    | Target | Value 
setSpeed   | 3000
setTimeout | 50000
```